# Oauth authentication facebook - cakePHP plugin

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, oauth, facebook-login

I am confused with this [plugin](https://github.com/MozMorris/FacebookAuthenticate-CakePhp-Authentication-Handler).

Just copy-paste the demo, but I am getting this error when i am trying to connect with facebook:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

full code:

```
<?php

class ExamplesController extends AppController {

  public $components = array(
    'Auth'=> array(
      'loginAction' => array(
        'controller' => 'examples',
        'action'     => 'login'
      ),
      'loginRedirect' => array(
        'controller' => 'examples',
        'action'     => 'my_account'
      ),
      'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
      'authenticate' => array(
        'FacebookAuth.Facebook' => array(
          'fields' => array(
            'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );

    public function index() {
    }

  public function beforeFilter()
  {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->authenticate['FacebookAuth.Facebook']['application'] = array(
      'id'     => Configure::read('facebook.app_id'),
      'secret' => Configure::read('facebook.app_secret')
    );

    $this->Auth->allowedActions = array_merge($this->Auth->allowedActions, array('login'));
  }

  public function login()
  {
    if (!$this->Auth->login()) {
      /**
       * Get config for Facebook redirect
       */
      $clientId    = Configure::read('facebook.app_id');
      $permissions = implode(',', Configure::read('facebook.permissions'));
      $redirect    = Router::url(false, true);
      $csrfToken   = CakeSession::read('FacebookAuthCSRF');

      $this->redirect(Configure::read('facebook.oauth_dialg_url') . '?client_id=' . $clientId . '&redirect_uri=' . $redirect . '&scope=' . $permissions . '&state=' . $csrfToken);
    } else {
      $this->redirect(array('action' => 'my_account'));
    }
  }

  public function my_account()
  {
    var_dump($this->Auth->user());
    die();
  }
}
```

the challenge is to figure out how to put the plugin working.

---

**UPDATE:**
Ok, i have this url  (thanks to elliot):

```
http://someHost/?client_id=4003xx16796&redirect_uri=http://localhost/cake/users/login&scope=email&state=f96419881df77cdc689e6c43c131cf3b
```

Now, what is supposed to do with the url? The next step, basically. What I have is just a loggin button, that when clicked change the url, like the demo above, but without any action. The response is empty.

I already read [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the issue

```
Configure::read('facebook.oauth_dialg_url')
```

Should read:

```
Configure::read('facebook.oauth_dialog_url')
```

Also make sure you're making the appropriate Configure::write commands in bootstrap.php

```
Configure::write('facebook.oauth_dialog_url', 'http://some-value.com/path/to/url');
```